# React-App - Error while doing npm run build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm having this problem when I do npm run build for production:

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file:

```
./node_modules/axios-token-interceptor/index.js:19

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myanmar-club-web-app@0.1.0 build: `react-app-rewired build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myanmar-club-web-app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

It was fine when I run locally.
Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Consider editing your question. Share your package.json code and build script. Not enough information and it's unclear what went wrong.

Comment: Check line 19 on https://github.com/sandrinodimattia/axios-token-interceptor/blob/master/index.js as per your first line